# Post in the wall of a Facebook user

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

My question is very simple and has been answered lots of times in Stackoverflow but in order to the changing of the Facebook API I want to make certain if a user who is using my app can post to their wall a message generated automatically by the app.

If the user is reading in my app a comment he/she likes, I want he/she can post to their wall a message like "I've been reading a very interesting comment about..." and I would like that tis text appears automatically in the window where Facebook requests permission to the user to post in their wall.

I've tried the JS API with "feed" method but the text in the field message is ignored. I'm going to try with PHP API but I think the result will be the same.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: do you know you can send an auto post with whatever you want without the dialog if the user authenticated?

Comment: @Chamilyan it is bad! =D

Comment: if it was so bad Facebook wouldn't have it as a feature. The user is giving permission to do this. ;)

Comment: @Chamilyan I know Facebook have this feature, but users don't like it.

Comment: @Chamilyan, I don't know and I would love to know how. Then, I could make my proper request window to ask the user to post in the wall. I'm dealing with scope and permissions and I don't know much about that right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### JavaScript SDK

You can send the following values using the JavaScript SDK:

```
// calling the API ...
var obj = {
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
  picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
  name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
  caption: 'Reference Documentation',
  description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
};
```

(code and image taken from [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/))

I described, what field is what text in the popup.
If not provided, name, image, caption and description are derived from the webpage, given in the link.

[image: Facebook Feed]

You *cannot* include a default message in the JS popup.

### PHP SDK

If you are using the PHP SDK, you can however include a message.

Code example:

```
try {

    $facebook->api(
        "/{$facebookId}/feed",
        "POST",
        array(
            // this is the important part
            'message' => "This is your message!",

            'link' => $yourLink,
            'name' => "This is your name",
            'caption' => '..',
            'description' => '...',

            'type' => 'link',
            'application' => array(
                'name' => 'Name of your app',
                'id' => $idOfYourApp
            )
        )
    );
}
catch (\FacebookApiException $exception)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the "message" field in feed no longer works. You have to use "description" or "caption"

This is because Facebook mentioned something along the lines of "A user should be able to say what they want about content on the internet".

Comment: Thanks. I've verified right now that I can post the 'message' from PHP API but not from JS API. Another silly question: I'm loging in with JS API but using PHP API. I've not obtained any access token. Has JS API obtained one or am I using authentication wrongly?

Comment: i have used this code its working fine but at here we need to click  on share button for posting information on wall.I want posting information on facebook wall without click on share button means information posted on wall during page load.